# SELECT IF rows to multiple columns

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, group-by

Hello I am seeking assistance with my query which currently runs without errors but does not display data as I need it too. My table stores phone numbers and the relevant fields are id, phonetype and phonenumber.

When ran it returns the columns `id`, `HOME PHONE`, `WORK PHONE`, `CELL PHONE` as expected though it ONLY displays the last number. Say there is a Home Phone and a Work Phone number in a given row... I only get data in the WORK PHONE column for that id. If there is a Home Phone, Work Phone and a Cell Phone in a row... I only get data in the CELL PHONE column.

I need one row of all phonenumbers for a given id in unique columns by phonetype. I hope that makes sense, if not the query should give you a idea what im looking for... thanks

```
SELECT id,
(IF(phonetype = 'HOME PHONE', phonenumbers.phonenumber, '')) AS 'HOME PHONE',
(IF(phonetype = 'WORK PHONE', phonenumbers.phonenumber, '')) AS 'WORK PHONE',
(IF(phonetype = 'CELL PHONE', phonenumbers.phonenumber, '')) AS 'CELL PHONE'
FROM phonenumbers
GROUP BY id;
```

The table I'm querying looks like this

```
id | name | phonetype | phonenumber

1  |  Jim  |  HOME PHONE | 0000000001        
1  |  Jim  |  WORK PHONE | 0000000002
2  |  Kim  |  HOME PHONE | 0000000003
2  |  Kim  |  WORK PHONE | 0000000004
2  |  Kim  |  CELL PHONE | 0000000005
```

The result I'm looking for would look like this...

```
id | name | home phone | work phone | cell phone

 1 | Jim | 0000000001 | 0000000002 | 
 2 | Kim | 0000000003 | 0000000004 | 0000000005
```

Comment: how can there be a work phone AND a cell phone in a GIVEN row, if you have a type? If the type = 'WORK PHONE' how can it also be 'CELL PHONE'? Looking at that query and imagining your database, I would assume each resulting row would have one column filled and the other two blank.

Comment: i see where i created confusion, the table has multiple rows of phonetypes for each person. So Jim has a work, home and cell number each on their own row.

Comment: no confusion, that's exactly how I understood it, but then you're going to wind up with multiple rows of results for Jim, and each row will still only have one value filled in.  I think you're hoping to merge these individual rows into a single row result, which you can do with subselects as per d'alar'cop's answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each ID has only one phone number of each type against it:

```
SELECT a.id,
(SELECT phonenumbers.phonenumber FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonetype = 'HOME PHONE' AND id = a.id) AS 'HOME PHONE',
(SELECT phonenumbers.phonenumber FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonetype = 'WORK PHONE' AND id = a.id)  AS 'WORK PHONE',
(SELECT phonenumbers.phonenumber FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonetype = 'CELL PHONE' AND id = a.id)  AS 'CELL PHONE'
FROM phonenumbers a
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Might help.
Cheers.

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding "limit 1" to each subselect, cause you're bound to run into a situation where you'll have multiple results for a given user sooner or later and that would break everything.

Comment: I ran this solution and got a error 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row. I'm sure this is due to my poor description, there are multiple phone numbers and phone types per id. I added table example to original post to help clarify what im looking for. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so an ID may have many HOME PHONE numbers? - are they timestamped for validity?... you could wrap 'phonenumbers.phonenumber' in the sub-queries with distinct() or with max() or add a WHERE clause to get latest one maybe? Let me know.

Comment: I added more data to the table and result examples in the original post which I think will help greatly. There is only 1 HOME, CELL or WORK phonetype per ID. There is no timestamp and I will have to read a bit on distinct() and max(), still learning :) I think my new table and result example will get us on the same page, thanks again so appreciate your help!